# Is it possible to send an email in android without launching the corresponding application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, jakarta-mail

So sending an email is well documented on -  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email 
as follows:-

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

the above code i assume would open or ask you to open an email app(e.g. gmail) to send your email.

So i searched for another way to send a message without opening an app. and i found this :- http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/

The above link shows that you would have to basically build your own custom email app using gmail SMTP and JavaMail api

My question is, is there a way to send an email without

A. opening another application.

B. using external libraries like java mail etc?

Something like this :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUTNT.jpg

Comment: No.  Android does not have built in email APIs.  If you wish to send an email, either use an Intent or use an external library.  An Intent is usually preferred, as it gives the user a chance to change the message, and its set up to a working, authorized SMTP server.  This isn't like the 90s, you can't just take a random email app and point it at a random email server and expect it to work these days.  And if you want a UI for them like in the picture, why wouldn't you just use an intent and launch the user's preferred email client?

Comment: @Gabe because, and i might be a minority here, i detest being forced to switch between apps for some functionality provided in another app. Like i understand if you want to share something on whatsapp, facebook etc. you need to switch to that particular app but i consider email to be an essential functionality.

Comment: You're in the minority. Writing a good email client is hard. You have your app to write, you don't need to spend the time writing a second app that's already done, and do so in a worse way. And I'm going to have to spend significant time string it up (what smtp settings are you going to use? Are you going to run the server? If not, how do I auth? If so, how do you secure it and ensure I don't get caught as spam? ). It's just really not practical to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, if you consider the following to be "external libraries":

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;
```

If you do not consider those "external", I can give you code that works on Android 8.1 if you need. Tested with Gmail, Yahoo, and others.

Otherwise, AFAIK, there is no native Android API allowing one to send emails directly (i.e. not via an app).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can send email without using external libraries or opening an app.  There's no magic in JavaMail.  It's all code you could write yourself.  Start writing!  It's just going to be a lot more effort than using JavaMail, but if that's what you want you can certainly do it.

Comment: thank-you for the encouragement. But if there is no android api for mail and my only 2 options are JavaMail and writing the code myself i would just stick to JavaMail lol.

Comment: A very wise choice!  :-)